How to use deferred components
My app have a mini-game, but it's too heavy and it's an option for an event in this app. I try to use deferred components but i can't use it although I've read deferred Components. Hope anyone can help me how to set up. Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
